# ajax send data to "test.php", and then open "test.php" directly to show the result

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send an array from javascript to php via ajax function.
And I don't want show the result as callback, but immediately open the target php file and show the images.
I mean, I want open the php file directly on the server side.

I think this is quite simple, but I just have no idea.

My javascript looks like:

```
var stringArray = new Array("/images/1.jpg", "/images/2.jpg", "/images/3.jpg");
$.ajax({
     url: 'test.php',
     data: {stringArray:stringArray},
     success: function() {
              window.open('test.php'); // It opens test.php in a window but shows nothing! 
     },
});
```

the test.php file:

```
$stringArray = $_GET['stringArray'];
foreach($stringArray as $value) {
   echo "<img src=" . $value . "></img>";
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ajax is used to load in data into the same page. If you want to open another page you can just navigate to another page and write php code there? What's the point?

Comment: Ok, i live in Manhattan, and need to go to New Jersey. I'll take a train to Philadelphia and another one to New Jersey. Because logic.

Comment: (seriously) you don't need AJAX, simply navigate to the page as @Dieter said.

Comment: sry, maybe I just made my example too easy. Actually I have a large string to store many image urls, for example I have written down a string with 3 items. test.php needs this data to display images again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, You are sending data by post method and accessing in test.php
but when u open file via window.location it doesn't get POST data hence no data get populated

You can achieve it via $_SESSION.
in test.php

```
 session_start();

 if(!empty($_POST['stringArray'])) {
    $_SESSION['stringArray'] = $_POST['stringArray'];               
 } 

 $stringArray = (isset($_SESSION['stringArray']) && $_SESSION['stringArray'] != '') ? $_SESSION['stringArray'] : $_POST['stringArray']; 

 foreach($stringArray as $value) {
   echo "<h3>" . $value . "</h3>";
}
```

Hope this will work for you...

Comment: Hi, additionly, window open doesn't work on ipad safari. could you give me some information urls to this problem.

Comment: try to use window.location = 'test.php'; 

not sure try this out.

Answer (score 3):

Likely the window.open command is being called without the POST data needed.

Now, I don't know what you want to do here but, why send an Ajax request when you don't really want to make use of it?.

Edit: just to make it a bit clearer, you seem to be calling the php file with no data trough POST. There is no clean way of opening a window in JS with POST data, just try GET for no critical information. Let is know how it goes.

Comment: Actually I have a large string to store many image urls, in the example aboive I have written down a string with 3 items. test.php needs this data to display images again.

Comment: I think something (the big picture in this) may be missing. In what context is this used?. What does it strive to achieve?. Some solutions, albeit legal, are less than ideal or readable. Perhaps if you'd tell us where does this large string of urls comes from and what do you want to do with them, we'd come with a solution... The question itself has been answered but maybe there's more to discuss here.

Answer (score 1):

you should write

```
var stringArray = new Array("apple", "banana", "orange");
$.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'test.php',
     data: {stringArray:stringArray},
     success: function(message) {
              window.open(message); // It will open a window with contents.
     },
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. but I want really open the php file on the server side, no callback to local.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't show the output because when you open the page on the callback you are not sending anything through to the test page through the post variable. Why you would want to do this I don't know. Send the information through the url, get.

Comment: I have changed my code. "GET" doesn't work, too. Or I still missing something?